# libz conflict when running perl library

Tags: c++, mysql, perl, zlib

Running on CentOS 7
Linux coolname 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Our application is developed in Perl and calls c++ libraries using swig and also XS. It runs into Centos.

We have a CORE package called db.pm which is actually written into c++ and uses XS to allow PERL to call it.

Using the db.pm we have a perl code that uses package GD to print a png image . So this code loads db.pm , gets the DB data and creates a chart and tries to print it.

The issue we are having is when loading db.pm we believe libz is accessed and when using GD package it calls libpng which also uses libz. At this time when we try to print the image we have core dump.

The gdb bt is this one here  :
 [image]

```
 my $im = new GD::Image(100,100);

# allocate some colors
my $white = $im->colorAllocate(255,255,255);
my $black = $im->colorAllocate(0,0,0);       
my $red = $im->colorAllocate(255,0,0);      
my $blue = $im->colorAllocate(176,196,222);

# make the background transparent and interlaced
$im->transparent($white);
$im->interlaced('true');

# Put a black frame around the picture
$im->filledRectangle(0,0,50,50,'#f2f2f2');





# convert into png data
open my $out, '>', 'heatmap_img.png' or die;
binmode $out;
print $out $img->png;

print 'Success \n';

1;
```

Comment: The code works fine on my system (Ubuntu 19.04, GD::Image version 2.71). Can you also run the code above without using your `db.pm`? Do you get still get core dump?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this is CentOS 7. Yes still get a core.

Comment: Note that I needed to change the last argument to `filledRectangle()` to to a defined color, like `$red`, or else I got the warning: `Argument "#f2f2f2" isn't numeric in subroutine entry`

Comment: What's the question here? Do you know how to debug this? What happens when you upgrade zlib? There are various crash bugs fixed [after 1.2.7](https://www.zlib.net/ChangeLog.txt).